# Hide <td> with jquery based on input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I would like to hide `td` if `input` `value` is `0` but I can't get it to work?

http://jsfiddle.net/zxpsd8x6/1/

```
<td><input type="radio" name="hideifvalue0" value"0"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="hideifvalue0" value"1"></td>

<button class="btn1">Hide</button>
<button class="btn2">Show</button>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".btn1").click(function(){
 $("td").hide();
 });
 $(".btn2").click(function(){
 $("td").show();
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: this html is invalid. Td should be the child of tabla and tr

Comment: And it should be `value="0"` not `value"0"`. Are you looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zxpsd8x6/9/?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zxpsd8x6/12/

Comment: Thx for your help, but can i also hide an class on the same command? I have a label stored in another td : jsfiddle.net/swcmp2ws/1

Comment: The code in your jsfiddle should work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the way I would recommend, but this fixes the selectors:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swcmp2ws/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn1").click(function () {
        $('td:has(input[value="0"])').hide();
               //or
        $('input[value="0"]').parent().hide();
    });
    $(".btn2").click(function () {
        $('td:has(input[value="0"])').show();
               //or
        $('input[value="0"]').parent().show();
    });
});
```

**Notes:**

- Your HTML was invalid - added `table` and `tr` elements
- You should just use classes on common elements for simpler selectors (e.g. `class="hidethese"`) and `$('.hidethese').hide()`

Comment: The question was how to hide the TD if the input value was zero, not if it had a particular name. Your code would actually incorrectly hide both TDs.

Comment: This is still wrong. It needs to check if value="0" not if value="hideifvalue0"

Comment: the question is poorly worded, but I'm guessing the name on the input is only there for illustrative purposes.

Comment: @evilunix And the purpose of the hide/show buttons is? :)

Comment: To hide the table cells who's child inputs have a value of zero. Why - who knows!

Comment: @Milind Anantwar: Thanks for all the edits/fixes... it's like having a *ghost writer* :)

Comment: @Milind Anantwar: I think the OP needs re-writing (or re-wiring) too :)

Comment: Thx for your help, but can i also hide an class on the same command? I have a label stored in another td : http://jsfiddle.net/swcmp2ws/1/

Comment: @user3906056: You need something unique about those divs to decide which to hide or show (e.g. a class). The overall aim of this code is very vague, making it hard to add new features. Best to explain it in more details too :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to:

```
<td><input type="radio" name="hideifvalue0" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="hideifvalue0" value="1"></td>
```

Then your jQuery should be:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".btn1").click(function(){
     $("input[value='0']").parent().hide();
   });
   $(".btn2").click(function(){
     $("input[value='0']").parent().show();
   });
});
```

Comment: What if there is one more input type= text. then this code will effect that input as well .. Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes - it would, but given the example HTML, it shouldn't be a problem. We only need to have a selector as specific as is needed to solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your html elements are wrong. `<td>` should be inside `<table><tr>`
like:
`<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="hideifvalue0" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="hideifvalue0" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>`

`<button class="btn1">Hide</button>
<button class="btn2">Show</button>`

Then here your jQuery code goes:

`$(".btn1").on('click', function () {
    $("input:radio[value='0']").parent().hide();
});`

`$(".btn2").on('click', function () {
    $("input:radio[value='0']").parent().show();
});`

Comment: There is no need to iterate over the inputs, checking the value, when this can be incorporated into the actual jQuery selector.

Comment: Please check it and then down grade it. I have changed it :)